# Is there a tool/API to extract Minecraft recipes?

Tags: java, api, gradle, minecraft

A friend and I decided to code a discord bot in Java, using JDA. The idea is for the bot to give you a request Minecraft recipe (a picture of it). However, we don't want to have to download *every single* recipe (there are way too many of them). So I was wondering if there's something we can use that would give us the recipes with pictures and everything, like an API or a website that we can access from the Java code that would return something we can use. (No code attached since we haven't really done anything and it would serve no purpose).

Comment: I'm not sure this is the kind of question appropriate for Stackoverflow. Please read the [ask] section and the [help/on-topic] section.

Comment: You could write a webscraper to scrap the minecraft wiki

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if an API exists that can do that for you. If the problem is spending the time to download every single recipe I might recommend creating a webscraper that could get that data from you. Getting the images from a site like https://www.minecraftcrafting.info/ would be fairly straight forward using python and beautifulsoup (https://pypi.org/project/beautifulsoup4/). Hope that helps and good luck!

Comment: Thanks, the suggestion helped me find what I needed :)